# WITH ROLLUP GRAND TOTAL AND SUBTOTAL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, rollup

I have a script that produces a result set that is almost there! I'm trying to get subtotals and grand totals. I get sub totals on the year column and a grand total at the end. My goal is to get the final result to state "grand total" instead of subtotal. Please note that my final row, 'location' also returns as null due to the rollup function.

```
SELECT
  YEAR,
  COUNT(ACCOUNTS) AS 'ACCOUNTS',        
  SUM(BALANCE) as 'BAL',
  LOCATION AS 'LOCATION'
FROM 
  ACCOUNT A 
WHERE C.CREATE BETWEEN 
  DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()-1),0) 
  AND DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0)
GROUP BY 
  LOCATION, YEAR
WITH ROLLUP
```

result set...

```
YEAR  ACCOUNTS  BAL        LOCATION
----  --------  ---------  --------
NULL        11   80687.51  WA
NULL       107  592980.18  NULL
```

Desired result set...

```
YEAR          ACCOUNTS  BAL        LOCATION
----          --------  ---------  --------
sub total           11   80687.51  WA
grand total        107  592980.18  ALL
```

Comment: Why your question is tagged with `mysql` when you're using SQL Server? Please retag your question appropriately and format your code.

Comment: @peterm exactly where does it say SQL Server??

Comment: @peterm The tag [tag:sql] refers to the SQL language, and NOT a particular vendor's database system, such as Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @WarrenT: Does MySQL support `DATEADD`, `DATEDIFF`, and `WITH ROLLUP` now? I wasn't aware that had been added. The tag `SQL` refers to generic SQL that is compatible across multiple DBMSs; SQL that is dependent on a specific DBMS should include that tag as well to make it clear that is the case. This query is clearly not generic, ANSI standard SQL.

Comment: @KenWhite just because you know of one DBMS that *does* support those, does not indicate that is the target system being asked about.

Comment: @WarrenT: Please adjust your tone and attitude. You're coming across as extremely combative and argumentative; that's the second time you've taken an insulting tone. Please don't do that here. The [help] pages have information about acceptable behavior here towards others. Thanks. (And I know of many more than just **ONE**, thank you. Please don't prejudge my experience or knowledge.)

Comment: @KenWhite No offense was intended, but I probably should have avoided some of the emphasis.  Someone decided the OP did not know what DBMS they were using, and someone rather quickly took the tag off.  A debate ensued, and I am defending what I believe to be a valid position, until we hear from Chase.

Comment: @WarrenT: No harm, no foul. The debate seems to have all been on your part, though; Peter simply asked the poster to clarify the tag (as I would have, given the functionality used), and I merely asked you if MySQL had added support for the specific functions used, and pointed out that a generic SQL tag is just that - generic - and that this question used functionality that is far from generic. (Your comment to Peter specifically referred to the `sql` tag and nothing else.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41676/discussion-between-warrent-and-ken-white)

Comment: @WarrenT: Sorry; there's no discussion to continue in chat here. Until the poster clarifies what DBMS is being asked about, it appears that Peter and I are not the only ones that think it must be SQLServer and not MySQL; I don't see anything that further discussion would benefit here. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GROUPING_ID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510624.aspx) to identify the grouping set each row is aggregating

```
SELECT
   CASE GROUPING_ID(LOCATION, YEAR)
     WHEN 0 THEN YEAR
     WHEN 2 THEN N'Sub total: ' + STR(YEAR) 
     WHEN 3 THEN N'Grand total'
  END
   COUNT(ACCOUNTS) AS 'ACCOUNTS',      
   SUM(BALANCE) as 'BAL',
   LOCATION AS 'LOCATION'
 FROM ACCOUNT A 
 WHERE C.CREATE BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()-1),0) 
                    AND DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0)
 GROUP BY LOCATION, YEAR
 WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use CASE WHEN (GROUPING(ColumnName) = 1), like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(YEAR) = 1 AND GROUPING(LOCATION) = 1 THEN 'grand total'
       WHEN GROUPING(YEAR) = 1 AND GROUPING(LOCATION) <> 1 THEN 'sub total'
       ELSE YEAR END AS YEAR
  COUNT(ACCOUNTS) AS 'ACCOUNTS',        
  SUM(BALANCE) as 'BAL',
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(LOCATION) = 1 THEN 'ALL' ELSE LOCATION AS 'LOCATION'
FROM 
  ACCOUNT A 
WHERE C.CREATE BETWEEN 
  DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()-1),0) 
  AND DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0)
GROUP BY 
  LOCATION, YEAR
WITH ROLLUP
```