# Assign points by rank to players of multiple games

Tags: php, mysql, rank

I'm building a multi-game tournament scoreboard, where many players can play many games, many times. I want to assign points to players per game based on their rank for each game, not their actual score.

e.g.

**Donkey Kong**

```
Rank | Player  | Score  | Points Awarded    
1    | Player2 | 34,000 | 1,000    
2    | Player1 | 32,000 | 999    
3    | Player3 | 29,000 | 998
```

**Robotron**

```
Rank | Player  | Score  | Points Awarded    
1    | Player1 | 39,000 | 1,000    
2    | Player3 | 32,000 | 999    
3    | Player2 | 21,000 | 998
```

**Tournament Standings**

```
Player1 - 1,999 Points

Player2 - 1,998 Points

Player3 - 1,997 Points
```

So far I have ranking and points calculations working just fine...

```
SELECT 
    `id`, 
    `userID`, 
    `gameID`, 
    `gamescore`, 
    `rank`, 
    1001.0 - (rank) AS points
FROM (
    SELECT 
        `id`, 
        `userID`, 
        `gameID`, 
        `gamescore`, 
        @curr_rank := IF(@prev_rank = id, @curr_rank, @curr_rank + 1) AS rank, 
        @prev_rank := id
    FROM
        `submit_score`, 
        (SELECT @curr_rank := 0) y, 
        (SELECT @prev_rank := NULL) z
    WHERE `submit_score`.`tournID` = 2
    ORDER BY `gamescore` DESC 
) ranked_game;
```

But I need to be able to assign the points by rank-per-game and then have a grand total of points for each player that I can then show in a list.

Comment: First separate data from relations. Second - did points awarded always are going to be the same from 1st place to the lowest one? Is so move that business logic to the code.

Comment: yes the points are always the same per rank

Comment: OK - so move away that data from DB as this is redundant (as well rank per game). Then create an array (hash map) for each game from a query with a sort `desc` on the Score column (that will give you highest score as rank 1 etc) where the key is a rank number and values will be an array (list) of Player ID and the Score. Looping through that kind of array you can create temp variables (or an array again) with player IDs and assign to them awards points. At the end you should to end with total points for each player ID.

Comment: Can't do two queries?

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135033/with-rollup-grand-total-and-subtotal

Comment: No not really that I can see

Comment: Rollup should be of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your DB should to look something like

**Players**

```
ID | Player Nickname
1  | Player1
2  | Player2
3  | Player3
```

**Donkey Kong**

```
PlayerID  | Score  
Player2ID | 34,000 
Player1ID | 32,000 
Player3ID | 29,000
```

**Robotron**

```
PlayerID  | Score 
Player1ID | 39,000
Player3ID | 32,000
Player2ID | 21,000
```

DB should be only used to store data. Rank and awarded points should be moved to the code as those are redundant parts.

Then query each table with `desc` sort on score columns. That will create ranked tables with top scorer as #1 etc. That retrieved data store in arrays for each game with Key->Values where Key will be a rank # (1+ incremental) and Values can be other array with stored players data (after join) and a score or a string something like PlayerX | Score# if you need a score data for anything because for real you need only Players data sort on scores per game.

After that you need to loop through player table and create an array of players where you will store tournament points retrieved from looping each game array and decrease tournament points on each rank and assign to a proper player.

Hope it helps

PS.
For existing data I will create views something like

```
set @max_points=1000;
select Rank, Player, 
@current_points := IF(Rank = 1, @max_points, @current_points-1) AS points
from DonkeyKong
```

for each game

then do final view to sum all tournaments points

```
select dk.Player AS Player,(dk.Points + ro.Points) AS Total 
from RO_view AS ro 
left join DK_view AS dk 
on dk.Player = ro.Player
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at a place where I can make that level of structure change as many other processes pull from the submit_score table

Comment: @Joel'Maximus'GriffinDodd take a look on my idea with creating views per each game then create final view for a total sum. Is not perfect but should to work on your existing data

Comment: Well,the problem is I have over 5000 available game titles, and then 1000's of instances of each of those games at locations all over the world, having a table for each game instance is impractical.